# Notes keeps prompting me for POP passwords

Tags: macos, password, notes.app

The Apple Notes app (Mountain Lion) keeps asking me to enter passwords for my various email accounts (POP) that I've added to Mail. Mail does not prompt me to re-enter any passwords, but sometimes Notes will ask for the password twice before it accepts it. Thing is, I don't even want Notes to use my POP accounts, just iCloud. But there doesn't seem to be a way to turn notes off for a specific account.

Has anyone seen this issue? Is there a way to remove my POP accounts from Notes that I haven't discovered?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does `codesign -vv /Applications/Notes.app/` print something like `a sealed resource is missing or invalid`? If it does, the code signature is invalid, so the application isn't allowed to access the keychain automatically. Copying Notes.app from another Mac or a backup or upgrading to 10.9 would probably fix it.

You can disable email syncing in System Preferences:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the reply Lauri. The `codesign` command returns a valid response. I was able to uncheck the Notes from the various accounts (thanks for that) but if I try to turn them back on Sys prefs now says it can't find the settings for the account! Mail is unchecked and checking it gives me the same error, even though the account exists in Mail. A separate issue now, but -- jeez Apple!